# URLLoader Error#2032 issues in Air 3.8

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, flex4.5, flex4.10

I am looking for some help to address the below mentioned issue;

Ever since I upgraded the Adobe air version from 3.7 to 3.8 in my mobile (S4), my Android App started getting URL stream error #2032 when trying to contact an INTRANET URL (web service endpoint which is NOT open to internet). But works perfectly when trying to access URL's which are open to internet.Again if I downgrade the Air version in the mobile to 3.7 then everything works perfect.

1. This 2032 stream error happens only when I tried deploying the app to an actual android device (S4 / Jelly Bean) and use it.
2. No issues when trying  to access same URL through the emulator (Flash Builder).
3. The android device which I used for testing is SUCCESSFULLY (authentication successful) connected to the intranet network through WIFI.
4. I am using Flash Builder 4.7 and Apache Flex 4.10 SDK to develop the app.

This is how I use URLLoader to call web services;

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest();    
urlRequest.contentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";    
urlRequest.method = "POST";    
urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("SOAPAction",""));    
urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive"));    
urlRequest.url = "https://example.com/services/abcWebService"; //Intranet- NOT OPEN TO INTERNET    
urlRequest.data = "I have my soap request xml here";     
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();    
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,resultHandlerFunction);
urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, **ioErrorHandlerFunction**);
urlLoader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS, responseHandlerFunction);
urlLoader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, statusHandlerFunction);
urlLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandlerFunction);    
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

All the times UrlLoader ends up in the `ioErrorHandlerFunction`  with `stream error #2032`

The HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_Status doesn't give much information either, the status code is 0.

Should I make any changes to the way I use URLLoader?

The same code works good with Air 3.7

Comment: I am observing the same issue on both iOS and Android with FlashBuilder 4.7, Flex 4.6 SDK, AIR 3.8 SDK

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in AIR 3.8 related to SSL.  Try changing your URL to http.  I realize that may not be a solution, but it may help us diagnose it.